# Handling iOS game saves over multiple devices

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm currently developing an iOS game. It requires internet access to play and uses Game Center. I want to implement save games, without using `NSUserDefaults` so users can play on multiple devices and everything is connected to their unique [Game Center ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/playerID). Does Apple provide a way to sync save games via Game Center or do I have to take care of it? I would likely create a PHP script but I don't want IDs to be spoofed via a proxy or other means. If this is the best option, how would I go about doing that? I'm open to other ideas also. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what iCloud is for. You can store key-value pairs in the user's iCloud which will then by synched across all devices. [Designing for Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html).

Comment: Can't this be spoofed easily since the keys/values are all in plaintext?